# RegExp - remove everything between last underscore and extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove everything between last underscore and extension.
Let's assume that I've file names like:
`first_01.png`
`second_file_02.png`

I need to convert that strings to
`first_01.png => first.png`
`second_file_02.png => second_file.png`
with one regular expression. File names could be different.

I'm trying my best on regex101.com, but I still miss something... I've tried

```
/[^_]+(?=\.)/
```

...but that gives me `first_.png` and `second_file_.png`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: *"I'm trying my best on regex101.com, but I still miss something..."* What do your attempts look like? What result do you get instead of what you want? What about why that happens don't you understand?

Comment: `/[^_]+(?=\.)/`
that gives me
`first_.png` `second_file_.png`

Comment: Hi - To improve the question, use the "edit" link rather than comments. (I've done it for you this time. :-) )

Comment: I'll remember, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_` to match the `_` (obviously), then `[^_]+` to match what comes after it, with a positive lookahead assertion for the `.` of the extension following it (`(?=\.)`):

```
str = str.replace(/_[^_]+(?=\.)/, '');
```

```js
function test(str, expect) {
  var result = str.replace(/_[^_]+(?=\.)/, '');
  console.log(str, "=>", result, result == expect ? ": Good" : ": ERROR");
}
test("first_01.png", "first.png");
test("second_file_02.png", "second_file.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
(.*)_\d+(.*)
```

with this:

```
$1$2
```

Explanation: capture what's before and after the match. Match an underscore and 1 or more digits.